# Universal correct links from navigation partial (express.js & handlebars)

Tags: node.js, express, hyperlink, path, handlebars.js

this seems like a very stupid question, but I really can't figure out how to do my navigation links properly.

**I'm using express.js with handlebars as view engine.**

My **backend.handlebars** has a naviation bar and loads in every sub-page of my backend under "/admin". It looks like this:

```
<nav>
    <a href="./" class="active-nav">Dashboard</a>
    <a href="./add">Add Post</a>
    <a href="./edit">Edit Post</a>
    <a href="./categories">Categories</a>
    <a href="./statictext">Static Text</a>
</nav>
```

Now the correct routes are:

**[server-adress]/admin/** for the dashboard

**[server-adress]/admin/add** for adding posts

**[server-adress]/admin/edit** for the editing posts

etc.

Now the way I've setup my links sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.

Sometimes every link works correctly when I'm in a sub-route like "admin/add" and want to go to "admin/edit".

Sometimes every link works when I'm under the main "admin/" to every sub-page, but not the other way around.

And sometimes everything works as intended, mostly when I delete the dot in front of the slash and then add it back end, restarting both times.

This obviously is too much of a gamble when deployed. As I don't know the absolute adress due to changing servers, **I can't use absolute paths**.

How do I go about this correctly?